# Freeze width of columns in table already rendered

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

With a table already rendered, if I hide some row the width of the columns is dynamically recalculated per the contents:

```js
function switchRow(ixRow){

let table = document.getElementById('theTable');

let row = table.rows[ixRow];
let currentVisibility = row.style.display;

row.style.display= currentVisibility== 'none' ? 'table-row' : 'none';

}
```

```css
table{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<table id='theTable'>
<tr><td>Hellen</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
<tr><td>Montgomery</td><td>Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="switchRow(1)">Switch row 1</button>
```

Is there a simple way to "freeze" the width of all the columns after the first rendering so hidding/displaying keeps the witdh of all the table / columns?

**Edit to differentiate from the other question supposedly duplicated** What I am looking for is to keep the widths that have been calculated when the table has been rendered -whatever the rules explicit or implicit-. Once displayed the widths must be constant.
I do not want to add any width prior rules, I want the default rendering of the table but once rendered I look for no dynamic changes in widths.

Comment: Is there any issue to append width in CSS? e.g. `table{ width:200px } `

Comment: I will edit to make it clearer, I want to keep the dynamic widths calculated after the table has been rendered -whatever the rules explicit or implicit. Once calculated the widths must be constant

Comment: @Pete is it really a duplicate?

Comment: I am answering with a working snippet on the Fixed Table Cell Width answer because here I can't. @Pete to me it seem that this answer isn't a duplication of the other referenced, tru7 seems interested to handle columsn with unknown initial width, not simply fixed.

Comment: @tru7 here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092200/3359473. I knew I would get a downvote but you know what? I don't care. Hope this helps a bit. Because it's clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: @0xc14m1z Well, you got my upvote on the other thread. I am not sure of understanding why a question can be blocked by someone that says that there's an only way. At least your solution answers my question, shame that I cannot be further discussed here.

Comment: @0xc14m1z by the way, why did you foresee a downvote?, perhaps the answer might be refined but it works....

Comment: I knew I would get the downvote (and I got it few minutes later) because the answer is related to your question, which I still think is different from the one references by @Pete. So, for your answer is right, but for the other no, at least not properly. I tried to answer here, but nada. Glad it helped you :)

Comment: @0xc14m1z The question is now open so feel free to move your answer here and I will edit the edits

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to do it now! Thanks @Pete, hope you agree with us :)

Comment: @0xc14m1z You're still going to have the changing width problems if you then add a column that is wider than the original - but if you're just toggling, your solution will work. But if you don't want to do this the proper way then fill your boots.  I won't waste my time trying to teach people who don't want to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first compute the maximum cell widths after the page load and assign it to the cells, in order to be kept for later:

```js
window.onload = function () {
   const table = document.getElementById('theTable');
   const widths = computeColumnWidths(table)
   setColumnWidths(table, widths)
}

function computeColumnWidths(table) {
  const widths = Array.from({ length: table.rows[0].cells.length })
                      .fill(0);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
    const row = table.rows[i]
    
    for (let j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
      const cell = row.cells[j]
      widths[j] = Math.max(widths[j], cell.offsetWidth);
    }
  }
  
  return widths;
}

function setColumnWidths(table, widths) {
  for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
    const row = table.rows[i]
    
    for (let j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
      const cell = row.cells[j]
      cell.style.width = widths[j] + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function switchRow(ixRow){

  let table = document.getElementById('theTable');

  let row = table.rows[ixRow];
  let currentVisibility = row.style.display;

  row.style.display = currentVisibility == 'none' ? 'table-row' : 'none';

}
```

```css
table{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<table id='theTable'>
<tr><td>Hellen</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
<tr><td>Montgomery</td><td>Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="switchRow(1)">Switch row 1</button>
```